# Activity from a suspended user account

Tags: support

There is one user who appeared to login yesterday despite having his account locked out due to SE term violations. The lock out period is still in effect.

**How is it possible to have activity then in this case?**

Comment: How did you notice this?

Comment: @JimG. Suspension is rare so users are often intrigued when they see a post from a 1-rep user for the first time and click the profile to find out why he has only 1 rep. The "last seen" stat is prominently placed on that page. Other users may check the profile to find out when the suspension expires and will also see the stat.

Answer (score 14):

Suspended users can still log in and visit the site, same as a non-user or logged-out user can.  They just can't *do* anything here -- posting, commenting, voting, editing, and so on.

Suspensions aren't meant to be punitive; they're intended to correct a problem.  If reading the site during the suspension period helps someone to come back as a productive contributor when it ends, I'm all for it.

Comment: And it's not exactly like we could stop them reading the site - all they'd have to do is log out.